# Ionic view app not updating pages

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I have created an Ionic 2 app, when i drag a page down using the (ionRefresh) function lists which are created are updated from a remote server and displayed on the page. This works perfectly on the 'ionic serve' browser view and in the android emulator on the pc, however when using the Ionic View app, the pages do not update. Any ideas why this might be? I'm not even sure where to look and I can't find any similar problems online.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a little late, but have you tried clearing the cache through the view app? Also, you can go into your ionic.config and .io-config and delete the app id so it will give you a new version of your app. This usually worked for me.